# Calling one class from another when action performed

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, jbutton

I have this game/test class of an  flappy bird example, and i have a Login Screen, upon clicking a JButton "loggin" in this screen class i would like to call the flappyBird class Below.

I have Tried something like this but with no luck

```
if(event == jButtonLogin){
this.dispose();
FlappyBird bird = new FlappyBird();
bird.setVisible();
```

//since it has Jframe in it i though this logic would work.

IF someone can point me the right way please

```
 public class FlappyBird implements ActionListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {

    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static FlappyBird flappyBird; //creating a static flappybird so it can be acessed within main

    public final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;   //scren size of the game
    public int highScore = 0;

    public Renderer renderer;
    public Random rand;

    public Rectangle bird;

    public int ticks, yMotion, score; //bird movement
    public boolean gameOver, started;

    public ArrayList<Rectangle> columns;    //arrrayList of Recatangles names column


    public FlappyBird()
    {
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();    //main frame of game

        Timer timer = new Timer(20,this);

        renderer = new Renderer();
        rand = new Random();

        jframe.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //  jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.addMouseListener(this);
        jframe.addKeyListener(this);
        jframe.setTitle("FlappyTest");
        jframe.add(renderer);    //need to create what were rendering

        bird = new Rectangle(50 - 10,HEIGHT/2 - 10,20,20);
        columns = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);
        addColumn(true);

        timer.start();
    }

    public void addColumn(boolean start){
        int space = 350;
        int width = 100;
        int height = 50 + rand.nextInt(300);   // height of column //minum = 50 // and talles being random at 300

        if (start)  //if first pipes
        {
            columns.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH + width + columns.size() * 200, HEIGHT - height - 100, width, height));  //top pipe
            columns.add(new Rectangle(WIDTH + width + (columns.size() - 1) * 200, 0, width, HEIGHT - height - space));   // bot pipe 
        }
        else
        {
            columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size() - 1).x + 300, HEIGHT - height - 100, width, height)); //top pipe
            columns.add(new Rectangle(columns.get(columns.size() - 1).x, 0, width, HEIGHT - height - space));  //bot pipe
        }
    }

    public void paintColumn(Graphics g, Rectangle column)    //passing theses two vriable on the method
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green); //darker()
        g.fillRect(column.x, column.y, column.width, column.height);
    }

    public void jump()
    {
        if(gameOver)
        {
            bird = new Rectangle(50 - 10,HEIGHT/2 - 10,20,20);
            columns.clear();
            yMotion = 0;
            score = 0;

            addColumn(true);
            addColumn(true);
            addColumn(true);
            addColumn(true);

            gameOver = false;
        }

        if(!started)
        {
            started = true;
        }
        else if(!gameOver)
        {
            if (yMotion > 0)
            {
                yMotion = 0;
            }
            yMotion -=15;
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)    //action being performed on the timer (20,THIS)
    {
        int speed = 10; //columns speed

        ticks++; //keeping count of each tick of the bird

        if(started)
        {

            for(int i = 0;i < columns.size(); i++)
            {
                Rectangle column = columns.get(i);

                column.x -= speed;
            }
            if(ticks % 2 == 0 && yMotion < 15)   
            {
                yMotion += 2;
            }

            for(int i = 0;i < columns.size(); i++)  // for the whole columns ArrayList
            {
                Rectangle column = columns.get(i); // grab column at whichever i postion

                if(column.x + column.y < 0)   // column x.y less than 0
                {
                    columns.remove(column);   //remove that current column
                    if(column.y == 0)   //if the column.y == 0 when it turns 0 and you have no more starting columns
                    {
                        addColumn(false);   // you add the other columns false // infinite loop
                    }
                }
            }

            bird.y += yMotion;

            for(Rectangle column : columns)
            { // FOR EACH RECTANGLE column IN COLUMNS
                if(column.y == 0 && bird.x  + bird.width / 2 > column.x + column.width / 2 - 10 && bird.x  + bird.width / 2 < column.x + column.width / 2 + 10)
                {
                    score++;
                }
                if(column.intersects(bird))
                { //colision detection with pipes
                    gameOver = true;
                    if(bird.x < column.x)
                    {
                        bird.x  = column.x - bird.width;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(column.y != 0){   //if its not the top column
                            bird.y = column.y - bird.height;
                        }
                        else if(bird.y < column.height)
                        {
                            bird.y = column.height;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(bird.y > HEIGHT - 100)  // if the Y becomes greater then the ground or if its less than 0
            {
                gameOver = true;
            }

            if(bird.y + yMotion >= HEIGHT - 120)
                bird.y = HEIGHT - 100 - bird.height;
            }
        renderer.repaint();   //EVERY 20 WE CALL REPAINT USING THE RENDERER TO UPDATE IT+
    }

    public void repaint(Graphics g) //MAIN SCREEN REPAINT
    {
        //System.out.println("Teste");
        System.out.println(bird.y);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);     //bground of the screen
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);     //blue line
        g.drawLine(0, HEIGHT-100, WIDTH, HEIGHT-100);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);    //White Screen
        g.fillRect(0,HEIGHT-98,WIDTH, HEIGHT-100);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);     //adding bird component
        g.fillRect(bird.x,bird.y,bird.width,bird.height);

        for (Rectangle column : columns)
        {
            paintColumn(g, column);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",1,100));

        if(!started)
        {
            g.drawString("Click to Start!", 75, HEIGHT / 2 - 50);
        }

        if(gameOver)
        {
            g.drawString("GAME OVER!", 75, HEIGHT / 2 - 50);
            if(score > highScore){
                highScore = score;
            }
        }
        if(!gameOver && started)
        {
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(score),WIDTH/2-25, 100);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial",1,20));
        g.drawString("High Score : " + highScore, 10, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        flappyBird = new FlappyBird(); // creating a new instance of flappybird
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        jump();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
        {
            jump();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) 
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: consider using a CardLayout to switch between views and some kind of model to share the data as needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer im sorry, but could you be more specific

Comment: Consider using a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), this will allow you to change the component which is visible to the user within the a single frame. You can use a model (object) which contains the properties you want to share between them by creating a single instance and passing to all the views that need it, something like [m-v-c](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: When you hit login, you want to show another JFrame - is it correct?

Comment: @MadProgrammer thx for taking ur time on this, i will look into, thanks again

Comment: @Pasupathi yes, correct when the action is performed in the Jbutton i would like to display the game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider looking into layout managers to achieve the behavior of a state-based game.

Ex: In your main method, rather than calling new FlappyBird() you would instead call something like new Login().

Be careful in the creation of the Login object - you don't want to necessarily reinvent the wheel by "opening" and creating a second JFrame (an undesirable band-aid solution can be done by hiding JFrames but that isn't what you want).

Instead, as MadProgrammer hinted at - Layout managers can instantly allow your application swap environments. Some retooling is in order to accomplish this design, but overall it is more modular, scalable (if you want to include an options page), and more OOP-oriented.

Ultimately, from the Login object, the user will be able to click a button that swaps the Layout to the Play Layout (which is where all of your FlappyBird stuff is).

Comment: thanks, this did help. if i could get some examples of what to do with the code and point me the right way